# Word for reverse blink

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an English word which means a "reverse blink?" By this I mean, having your eyes closed and then opening them for a fraction of a second and then closing them.

This question was inspired by http://what-if.xkcd.com/115/

Comment: You could call it a "knilb"...

Comment: Hey! I was gonna ask this! :)

Comment: @Marthaª It looks like I have found a way to get instant rep on a StackExchange site: Wait for relevant question to be asked on xkcd and then ask that question on StackExchange. Instant upvote and commenting privlages. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking about "[peek](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peek)". That is to look quickly through the eyes, like a game of peek-a-boo. You don't have to use your hands though.

> peek  (pk)
>   intr.v. peeked, peek·ing, peeks
>   1. To glance quickly.
>   2. To look or peer furtively, as from a place of concealment.
>   3. To be only partially visible, as if peering or emerging from hiding: Tiny crocuses peeked through the snow.
>   n.
>   A brief or furtive look.
>   [Middle English piken, perhaps alteration of Middle Dutch kieken, variant of kken.]
>   The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition copyright ©2000 by Houghton Mifflin Company. Updated in 2009. Published by Houghton Mifflin Company. All rights reserved.

If you are standing in the surface of the sun for a nanosecond, a peek would be the best you could do- although I wonder if Randall Munroe was seeking to emphasize how brief this "peek" would need to be.  A peek can be several seconds, and as he suggests, even a nanosecond in the interior would be far too long.

To be fair, a nanosecond on the surface would warm you up, but not burn you - but several microseconds might.  A peek is probably longer than that - I suspect he is alluding to "the blink of an eye" to underscore the brevity.

What I wonder is if a peek would blind you...

Comment: To my knowledge peek is more often used to look secretly, not for a very short time. There might be a better/less ambiguous word for the reverse blink.

Comment: Nope - it has both meanings. I agree, my first connotation is to look secretly, but it can mean just a quick glance - such as "I'll drop into that store and take a peek at the prices."  Doesn't mean you are trying to hide anything, just that you are going to get out of there before your girlfriend pulls out your wallet.

Comment: As an aside, lighthouses are said to flash if the light is obscured more than it shines, and occulating is when the signal shines more than it is obscured.